# How can I set the base directory used for assembly resolution in a CLR (.NET) instance hosted in a C++ application?

Tags: c++, clr

I am hosting the .NET 4.0 CLR in a C++ application. I use the [CLRCreateInstance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/hosting/clrcreateinstance-function) API to intialize the CLR. That works fine, but I want to change the "working directory" of the created CLR instance. I want it to use a specific directory for resolving assemblies, which is not the default behaviour.

**How can I set the working directory of a CLR instance hosted in a C++ app?**